# Select all rows of a SQL table which do not share a name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, call it `widgets` which has columns `name` and `created_at`, among others.  I want to run a query that returns the count of all the rows of `widgets` which share the same name and have been created within a millisecond of each other.

This is the query that I have come up with, but it returns a number greater than the total number of rows in the table, can someone point out where I am going wrong?

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT "t1"."id")
FROM 
  "tasks" "t1" ,"tasks" "t2"
WHERE 
  "t1"."name" = "t2"."name" 
AND 
  date_trunc('milliseconds',"t1"."created_at") = date_trunc('milliseconds',"t2"."created_at")
```

Comment: Did you add Klin suggestion. That mean that solve the problem or you already have that line?

Comment: His suggestion worked so I updated my query, I marked his answer as correct.

Comment: You shouldnt do that. Because now someone came and see the answer is the same as the question and wont understand where is the problem. Instead just accept the answer and other will understand that solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the condition:

```
and "t1"."id" <> "t2"."id"
```

where "id" is a primary key. In the lack of a primary key you can use `ctid`:

```
and "t1".ctid <> "t2".ctid
```